# How can I use my office computer at home seeing it in a window?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-control

I know I can do it but I don't know how. The university had a pdf how to use PuTTy, but it's not what I like. I want to see the desktop in a window so I can easily go to my folders and take a file I saved there and now I felt that I needed it. It will bother to go to office and come back just for one computation file! Also I may have a software there but not in my laptop at home, so I may need to do a computation using that, I think just typing some commands in a black page in PuTTy is not what be in use for that! If there is a command I have to use in PuTTy or any other program which can be in use, I will be too happy to know about it as it will save a lot of time in my study.

I use windows both in office computer and in my personal laptop.

Comment: Have you posed this question to the IT department at your University?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the policies put in place by the IT team at your office. Some companies will point blank refuse to allow you to do this. You will need to talk to them if this is something they can provide.

If they do allow this, the service is usually provided by [RDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) over a VPN for security.

Also, on a personal note, ask yourself this do you REALLY want your company to know you can work from home. They would love it if you worked for free on your own time.

Comment: Your question is very unclear on this, perhaps you should reword it to explain what your requirements are.

Comment: Yes, IT section answered me how to use VPN and RDP.

Answer (score -1):

RDP over VPN is the best corporate thing.
You can also encapsulate RDP with a putty SSH tunnel :
http://www.kettering.edu/offices-administration/information-technology/networks-security-storage/remote-desktop/remote

If you want a quick win, that can be against your corporate policy, just install teamviewer on both computer with option installing Unattended Access.
If your corporate firewall is not blocking it ...
https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/windows.aspx

Comment: try just teamviewer in this case